# Implementing IStoreSagaData which arcives

Tags: rebus

I'm finding that IStoreSagaData.Delete is not called on when a saga calls MarkAsComplete during the first message.  Is this by design? This makes it impossible to keep an archive of sagas which have completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is true - it's a consequence of the code being so "intelligent" that it knows not to do anything about a saga that is immediately marked as complete.

This also means that it would not be easy to find a way to hook in that functionality yourself - at least in Rebus versions <= 0.84.0.

Rebus versions >= 0.90.0 (also known as "Rebus 2") is much easier to extend in every way, and I've created [this issue](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/issues/332) because I think a good saga state auditing function would be an awesome feature in Rebus.

I might get around to add it one of the following days.